# Java 8: aggregate an item list by values and to regroup by position range

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I wan't to use Stream API for ordering and create lists in a tidy way. Maybe it's not possible to do this directly with Stream.
The final goal is to do statistics on datas. But this is not the problem.

The source is from *ffprobe* and it's a simple list of frame informations: position, type (I or B/P), and others informations for stats.
The parsing is ok: I have a big *List of Frame*s.

A Frame is like:

```
int position = 454
enum type = I
... // others datas for stats
```

Ok, now I wan't to regroup Frames by GOP list. A GOP, "Group of pictures", is a list of video frames. It start always with a frame type "I". A GOP can by like IPBBPBBPBBP. The size (nb of frames) and the order can change in the video stream. I can't predict it.

How I restore a GOP list?

```
1) I start my first GOP with the first frame (position = 0, type = I).
2) for each next frames, I check the type. If type = B or P, I add this frame to my current GOP.
3) but if this frame type is a "I", I "close" the current GOP list, create a new GOP list, and I add this frame. Goto 2) as long as there are frames.
```

Ok, it's not too complex to implement this with *for loop*.

But, with Stream and its friends (Collectors), how I can to do this?! Can this go faster than old-fashion *for*?

Thanks for reading and have a nice day.

PS: it's for an open source app.

*EDIT: After a simple test, for loop stay really fast up to 155000 frames: on one simple i7 core, 74 ms for doing the job (and take even less time to just open the data file).
So... the stream API seems to not be required.
But now, the Eugene’s answer is very instructive. Thank you Eugene!*

Comment: In my mind streams are not well suited for this kind of job. I saw [Eugene’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44090679/5772882), and if you’re happy with it, please don’t let me subtract from that. Streams are best for processing elements independently, maybe grouping by some inherent attribute of each element, but not by closest previous `I` element. I tend to prefer the loop solution here.

Comment: @OleV.V. generally I would go for a loop too, unless there would be a compiling reason not to. I did try to put up (in the second answer) such a reason - where a custom collector could be implemented that could deal with *lots* of entries in parallel; not that easy for a loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to clutter the other answer, I thought (I swear I saw this somewhere already!) of showing another custom collector.

```
List<List<Frame>> custom2 = list.stream()
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    () -> {
                        List<List<Frame>> supList = new ArrayList<>();
                        supList.add(new ArrayList<>());
                        return supList;
                    },
                    (l, frame) -> {
                        if (frame.getType().equals("I")) {
                            l.add(new ArrayList<>());   
                        }
                        l.get(l.size() - 1).add(frame);
                    },
                    (left, right) -> {
                        List<Frame> first = right.remove(0);
                        left.get(left.size() - 1).addAll(first);
                        left.addAll(right);
                        return left;
                    },
                    result -> {
                        result.remove(0);
                        return result;
                    }));
```

I'll try to explain it visually (for a parallel stream) of what is going on here. Suppose that the input is this:

`IPBIHGIR`

This is what it is going on for a parallel collector.

```
[() (I)]   [(P)]   [(B)]  [() (I)]   [(H)]   [(G)]   [() (I)]   [(R)]  
  \         /        \       /         \       /        \         / 
   \       /          \     /           \     /          \       /
  [() (I, P)]        [(B) (I)]          [(H, G)]        [() (I, R)]
       \                 /                  \               /                
        \               /                    \             /
         \             /                      \           /
          \           /                        \         /
         [() (I,P,B) (I)]                     [(H,G) (I, R)]
               \                                    /
                \                                  /  
                 \                                /
                  \                              /
                   \                            /
                    \                          /
                    [(), (I,P,B) (I,H,G), (I,R)]
```

The `finisher` just trims the first empty array.

And I'll just repeat that **again** : I saw this somewhere already (and it took a while to understand at that time), thus the drawing - may be it will help others.

In case you read this and know the original source, plz leave a comment and I will gladly put it into the answer, so that people know the true creator of this...

Comment: Wow... this is really clever...
A video file can be have a lot of frame. For a 2 hours movie @ 60 frames per seconds... Java will take in the face 2*3600*60 = 432.000 frames object.

Comment: ...that's a lot of items to manage by the JVM... 
While waiting responses here, I've implemented a for loop, and it seems pretty fast. Do you thing the stream API will be faster and less memory eater ?

Comment: @hdsdi3g when performance is important, I first *measure*, then *think about it*. Streams are going to use `more memory` for sure, as far as the speed goes - you can't easily parallelize a for loop... So measure - I can't really tell. If you have *enough* data (sounds like you do), a parallel stream might perform faster indeed.

Comment: Hi Eugene, while I see this works, I fail to see why adding an extra "row" at the beginning and removing it at the end is better for a parallel stream.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that took quite a while to figure out (thus the big time gap between the two answers) and I'm not quite sure I can explain that properly without drawing a lot. In short it is like a token that splits this row with the next one. Suppose this input `[() (I)]  [(P)] [(B)] [() (I)]  [(H)]`. And it turns out that we need to accumulate these two : `[() (I)]` and `[(H)]`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner in order to denote which entries belong to which row I *need* to have an empty row, so that it *separates* the entries from `leftRow` and `rightRow`. I honestly hope I made some sense here...

Answer (score 2):

I've simplified your input a bit to test. So here is how I would imagine `Frame`:

```
static class Frame {

    private final int position;

    private final String type;

    public Frame(int position, String type) {
        super();
        this.position = position;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "pos = " + position + " type = " + type;
    }

}
```

And than here is how I would solve it:

```
List<Frame> list = 
         Arrays.asList(
              new Frame(0, "I"),
              new Frame(1, "G"), 
              new Frame(2, "B"), 
              new Frame(3, "I"), 
              new Frame(4, "B"));

    int[] indexes = IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .filter(i -> list.get(i).getType().equals("I")),  
                    IntStream.of(list.size()))
            .toArray();

    List<List<Frame>> frames = IntStream.range(0, indexes.length - 1)
            .mapToObj(x -> list.subList(indexes[x], indexes[x + 1]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result will be:

```
[[pos = 0 type = I, pos = 1 type = G, pos = 2 type = B], 
   [pos = 3 type = I, pos = 4 type = B]]
```

`indexes` will capture the index where there's a "I" also appending the size of the list. And than a simple sublist to get the desired lists.

Now this **will not be** as fast as a for-loop, so not a performance gain here. Generally streams are slower then usual for-loops. The only performance gain you could get it when using `parallel` streams - but you would need *lots* of elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

After a simple test, for loop stay really fast up to 155000 frames: on one simple i7 core, 74 ms for doing the job (and take even less time to just open the data file). So... the stream API seems to not be required. But now, the Eugene’s answer is very instructive. Thank you Eugene!